# Load of multiple image files from a remote repository ios7

Tags: objective-c, ios7, loading, sdwebimage

In my project i have about 100 images all tiled to display large zooms with CATiled methods. These are a lot of files that, if put in a local bundle, rapidly make the app bundle too big.
I want to load these files from a web repository, using SDWebImage or any other sdk. 
Can you suggest any method to achieve this? Please keep in mid we are not talking of loading a single image, or multiple images for a UITableView, but lots of little tiled images that will be used when the user make zoom in a given view, and therefore this tiles have no UIImageview object to hold them, they are just in the bundle (now).
We are using ios7.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not clear what kind of solution you're looking for here, just download them.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I can't use a simple "sd_setImageWithURL" , for example, because the routines using the tiled images "need" all the images inmediately available, the loading will be too long. Keep in mind it can be about 30-40 tile images for just one image.

Comment: Yes, so just download the images quietly before they're needed. Without more information we can't make any specific suggestion. Just use a URL session.

Comment: But, if i download the images (it can be about 50*30 individual files) and put them in an array, wouldn't that abuse of the memory? I don't want a memory warning!

Comment: Save them to disk and then load only the ones you need to memory, when you need them.

Comment: O-k... I will look how to do that with SDWebimage... Thank you very much Wain. Just another question, can you recommend any tutorials or other sources adressing to this question?